# Slow open file dialog in Excel on Terminal Services 2008

Tags: terminal-server, microsoft-office-2010

Got a really frustrating problem with one of my clients systems.  They regularly create Excel spreadsheets with loads of hyperlinks to other files in.  Intermittently when they do this the open file dialog that appears when choosing to insert a hyperlink hangs for 30 seconds to a minute.

This will work fine for several days and then all of a sudden it won't work for a few days.  It happens with multiple files in different locations for different users.

Terminal server 2008 environment with Office 2010 and files stored on mapped network drives

Things checked for/tried so far:

- Removed any invalid shortcuts in the
  affected folders
- Got user to log off and back on to ensure drives connected properly
- Increased idle timeouts on network drives
- Disabled "Robustified UNC"
- Disabled automatic hyperlink formatting
- Disabled anti-virus

Everything I can find points to dodgy shortcuts or disconnected network drives but this does not seem to be the case here.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be something as simple as a CD or DVD in the optical drive.  This can explain the erratic behavior -- it can take many seconds for the drive to spin-up to read the title information in the dialog box.

Comment: The clients are all running thin terminals, so no CD drives.  Worth while checking for anyone else having this problem though so I modded you up.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by the Run command being disabled by group policy.  As soon as we enabled this, it all started working properly.